# How to change the ugly looking JavaScript file type icon in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

I'm just starting out to learn JavaScript, and I already hate the ugly looking icon that Microsoft uses for this file type. It's old and boring, looks like something that came right out of Windows 95.

[image: a]

I can't stand looking at it!

So I have decided to show you how to change it to something more appealing.

Comment: Close. That's the largely-unchanged icon from Windows Script Host, released with Win98. It was installable on 95 though. :)

Comment: Close as in "close this question"? Well cast a vote, if you feel like it's off-topic, or whatever. I don't understand your comment, what's it about anyway? The original icon? The new icon? The new icon is definitely not taken from the Windows Script Host, if that's what you're implying. The original icon, as depicted above, is the icon used for JScript files. The WSH icon is a cube with blue, red and green sides.

Comment: See third screenshot below to see what the WSH icon looks like.

Comment: No sorry, I mean close as in "nearly right" about the icon being from Win95. It was a joke; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

1. Head over to [NirSoft website](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) and download a program called
   "FileTypesMan v1.65".
2. Unpack FileTypesMan from the ZIP file.
3. Head over to [Icon Archive](http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=javascript) and search for "javascript" to find
   some nice icon you can use. Make sure you download the ICO version
   of it. *You can of course use your own icons as well.*
4. Now copy your ICO file to `%SystemRoot%\system32` or to the root of
   your C disk. Just make sure it's in some place you won't move it
   from at some point.
5. Run the FileTypesMan EXE file.
6. Press Ctrl+F and type in `.js` and then press Enter to locate this
   extension, and Esc to close the Find dialog box.
7. It should be already selected, if not, select it and press F2 to
   edit the file type.
8. In the field "Default Icon" click the button next to it to locate
   your ICO file. If you stored it to `%SystemRoot%\system32` it should
   be in `C:\Windows\system32` folder. *You can also type in the search
   path.* Click OK, then OK again to save changes.

You should now have something more pleasant to look at, like this:

[image: a]

*Icon created by Untergunter, licensed as CC Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0.*

This icon is nothing special really, but does look much better in a modern operating system such as Windows 7, than the default JScript icon that Microsoft uses. Another benefit of using this particular icon is that you get several icon sizes, so clicking the "change your view" button in Windows Explorer actually works for this file type, you get a nice big icon instead of the Windows 95 wreck you get by default.

You can use FileTypesMan program to change any file type icon on Windows 7. It's also portable, so no need to install it. Anthor way to accomplish the same result would be to use Registry Editor (regedit.exe). I won't cover that, since others have already done so.

*Credits go out to [HTG](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/) for explaining how to use this wonderful program.*

**Screenshots**

[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]
[image: e]

Comment: Don't copy stuff that doesn't belong there into Windows directories. Instead, create a folder in the system partition's root directory or similar.

Comment: How can an icon file be harmful, if you put it in the Windows folder? I'm just curious. You are free to change the instruction, if you wish.

Comment: It’s not about harm, it’s about order. That’s why there’s the `AppData` folder, the `Program Files` folder and friends. See also paragraph 10.5 in the [Certification requirements for Windows desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh749939.aspx).